# GRPC C++ Async Server How differentiate between WritesDone and broken connection

Tags: c++, asynchronous, server, grpc

When developing an Async C++ GRPC Server, how can I differentiate between the client being done with writing and the connection being broken ?

I am Streaming data from the client to the server and once the client is done it will call WritesDone to let the server know it should finish storing the file. If I have a sync server I can differentiate between the client calling WritesDone and the connection being broken by calling context->IsCancelled() but in async mode you can not call IsCancelled until you get the tag specified in AsyncNotifyWhenDone.

In both cases (WritesDone and Call done) the Read tag gets returned with ok set to false. However, the AsyncNotifyWhenDone tag, which would allow me to differentiate arrives after the read tag.

I will know after I try to call finish (it will also return false) but I need to know before I call finish as my final processing might fail and I can't return the error anymore if I already called finish.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to distinguish until the AsyncNotifyWhenDone tag returns. It may come after the Read in which case you may need to buffer it up. In the sync API you can check IsCancelled() anytime (and you can also do that in the Callback API which should be available for general use soon).